# How can I replace the desktop icon of a installed Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I changed the icon of my Blazor WebAssembly but the icon on the desktop is not updated. I can fix this with

Right click -> Properties -> Change icon -> only the new icon is shown -> OK -> OK -> The new icon is shown on the desktop

but I do not want to expect this from the user. Even when I delete and reinstall the app, the old icon is shown. Is there a way to automatically update the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple workaround: In Visual Studio I did not overwrite the old icon but added the new icon with a different name and changed the according paths. This way, not an old icon from a cache or where ever is used.